# Elegant and optimized solution to a function that group sublists under a threshold length in python

Tags: python, list, algorithm

Given a list `L`, for instance, `[[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1], [1]]` and a `max_len=8` I would like to create a new list `LN` like this `[[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1]]]`.

So I have a list of lists. I want to group the lists in a way that the sum of the lengths of each list is <= max_len. You need to retain the lists as they are, same order, so only consecutive lists can be grouped.

I've been trying to do it in the most Pythonic and efficient way. Should be O(n).
With the help of someone, this is the code I have so far:

```
def chunks(list_to_chunck, max_len):
    if any(len(sub_list) > max_len for sub_list in list_to_chunck):
        return None

    new_list = []
    while list_to_chunck:
        copy_list = [list_to_chunck.pop(0)]
        while list_to_chunck:
            if len(list_to_chunck[0]) + sum(len(sub_list) for sub_list in copy_list) <= max_len:
                copy_list.append(list_to_chunck.pop(0))
            else:
                break
        new_list.append(copy_list)

    return new_list
```

Comment: Please clearly state the problem with your code.  See [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `lst.pop(0)` kills your efficiency. It also mutates the list passed as an argument, a anti-pattern in almost all cases (perhaps a small, private helper function where this is done for efficiency and not exposed as part of a public API is a case where this might be acceptable).

Comment: @Prune I edited for more readable code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a variable `size` to keep track of the current size of the last sub-list in the output list, and whenever it's going to exceed `max_len` after adding the current sub-list in the iteration, append a new sub-list to the output. Initialize `size` with a value greater than `max_len` so that it will always add a new sub-list in the first iteration. With this approach the time complexity will be *O(n)*:

```
def chunks(lst, max_len):
    output = []
    size = max_len + 1
    for s in lst:
        size += len(s)
        if size > max_len:
            output.append([])
            size = len(s)
            if size > max_len:
                return
        output[-1].append(s)
    return output
```

so that `chunks([[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1]], 8)` returns:

```
[[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1]]]
```

Comment: But it fails if one of the sublists is larger than `max_len`, e.g. `chunks([[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1], [1]], 3)` gives `[[[1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1]]]` instead of `None` or similar.

Comment: @norok2 True, but, as in my code above I make sure to check if I have a sub_list larger than max_len.

```
if any(len(sub_list) > max_len for sub_list in list_to_chunck):
        return None
```

Comment: I see. Indeed I did not notice this part of the behavior of the OP's code. I've updated the answer accordingly. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sketch of an approach that will be O(N). It creates a new list, and doesn't modify the original. It doesn't handle all edge cases, but this should get you going:

```
In [1]: data = [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1], [1]]
   ...:

In [2]: def chunks(nested, maxlen):
   ...:     total = 0
   ...:     result = []
   ...:     piece = []
   ...:     for sub in nested:
   ...:         length = len(sub)
   ...:         if total + length > maxlen:
   ...:             result.append(piece)
   ...:             piece = [sub]
   ...:             total = length
   ...:         else:
   ...:             piece.append(sub)
   ...:             total += length
   ...:     if piece:
   ...:         result.append(piece)
   ...:     return result
   ...:

In [3]: chunks(data, 8)
Out[3]: [[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1]]]
```

Comment: Thank you also, but I prefer the other answer, which uses fewer lines of code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to have any constraints on total number of lists, so a greedy approach should be fine:

```
def chunks(items, max_len):
    ret = [[]]
    remaining = max_len
    for i in items:
        if len(i) > remaining:
            ret.append([])
            remaining = max_len
            if len(i) > remaining:
                return None  # Could raise on impossible
        ret[-1].append(i)
        remaining -= len(i)
    return ret
```

using your example:

```
items = [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1], [1]]
assert chunks(items, 8) == [[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1]]]
```

Seeing other answers, this is pretty much in line, so I wanted to toss in a less readable option, without the length guarantee =)

```
def chunks(items, max_len):
    count = [0, 0]
    def group(item): 
        count[1] += len(item)
        if count[1] >= 8:
            count[0] += 1
            count[1] = 0
        return count[0]
    return [list(v) for k, v in itertools.groupby(data, key=group)]
```

Answer (score 0):

A generator-based solution:

```
def group_subseqs(seq, max_len):
    curr_size = 0
    result = []
    for subseq in seq:
        len_subseq = len(subseq)
        if curr_size + len_subseq <= max_len:
            result.append(subseq)
            curr_size += len_subseq
        else:
            if result:
                yield result
                if len_subseq <= max_len:
                    result = [subseq]
                    curr_size = len_subseq
                else:
                    return
            else:
                return
    if result:
        yield result
```

working like expected (sort of... stops yielding if a sublist is larger than `max_len` instead of not yielding anything at all):

```
a = [[1,1,1,1], [1,1,1], [1,1], [1]]
print(list(group_subseqs(a, 8)))
# [[[1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1]]]

print(list(group_subseqs(a, 4)))
# [[[1, 1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1]], [[1, 1], [1]]]

print(list(group_subseqs(a, 3)))
# []

print(list(group_subseqs(a[::-1], 3)))
# [[[1], [1, 1]], [[1, 1, 1]]]
```